# Getting error trying to parse NSString into NSDate

Tags: objective-c

I'm total newbie so please forgive me if im doing something terrible here.

Im trying to take the user birthday in the format I specify in the example, but getting error in the `scanf` section:  `format specified type char * but the argument has type NSString`

How can I fix it? this is my code:

```
    int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSString *input;

        NSLog(@"Please enter your birthday, for example: 09-01-1984");

        scanf("%s", &input);

        NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

        NSDate *bDay = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:input];

        NSLog(@"%lu", [bDay elapsedDays:today]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sscanf()` is part of the C-library and `NSString` is part of the Foundation Objective-C framework and you cannot mix them like that.

Try this:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        char input[80];
        NSLog(@"Please enter your birthday, for example: 09-01-1984");
        scanf("%s", input);
        NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
        NSDate *bDay = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:input]];
        NSLog(@"%lu", [bDay elapsedDays:today]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: He means scanf returns a C string (pointer to array of char) but the ObjC API takes NSString. NSString is not the same as char *

Comment: @nielsbot Sorry I don't know what you mean.  Is there an error with the code I provided?

Comment: @trojanfoe no error--just trying to help clarify is all... but apparently I made it more confusing!